# Google Chrome not remembering scroll position after return back

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, browser-history, jquery-isotope

[Team-Site](http://www.ammarkt.ch/ueberuns/team/)

When going from Team-Overview to a Team-Member in Detail-View and then back by Browser-Button or the "Zurück"-Button (wich uses Browser-Back as well), chrome will remember the scroll position. But shortly after it will jump to the right position, it will jump back to top.

I can't imagine why it is doing so.

On that Page, metafizzy isotope Framework does the ordering of the Elements.

All other Browser have the right behaviour here.

Any Advices here would really be appreciated!

Comment: @Vprimachenko i will, as soon as i've been able to test the suggested solves. Sadly, i haven't until today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution would be to put an id on every `.mitarbeiter`, eg

```
<div id="john_doe" class="mitarbeiter"...
```

and put this id to the "Zurück" link eg,

```
<a class="light backlink_detail" href="/ueberuns/team#john_doe">Zurück</a>
```

and on the about page, wait till `metafizzy` is done and use `$.scrollTo(window.hash)` to scroll to previously selected team-member.

Comment: That seems a nice idea for a workaround. I will try it as soon as possible and let you know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The history of the position of the "scroll" is not something that there is a standard on how it should be treated when pressing back. This is up to every browser to handle how they see fit. Or do you mean that the framework has some mechanics for this?

You could have a java script that locally stores the information about the scroll locations in a cookie and reset it using java script when you move back in your page history?

Comment: Im sorry for my somehow unclear issue. I would like it to be default, so the browser SHOULD jump to the position he once was before i went to the detail-view. But somehow, chrome doesnt do it.

Comment: @JeremyZahner scrolling to prev position happens in chrome before `document::onready` you page is not big enough at that moment, as your layouting script did not run yet.

Comment: @Vprimachenko is there an "easy" way solving this? i guess not...?

Comment: @JeremyZahner: I would try to save the scroll position and then reset it using javascript when you go "back" to the page once your document was finished loading. In theory that should work just fine.